# 401 invalid_client when processing paypal payment using node SDK on production system

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment

I have a weird situation going on, I always get a 401 invalid_client error when trying to make a payment on my production system using the node SDK.
The credentials are a 100% correct, mode property is set to live and this config works on localhost - I can process the payment with no issues. So sandbox works on production and localhost, live works only on localhost. ENV variables are exactly the same when I simulate live mode on localhost. The debug id I get from PayPal is bc930e48644c9. Does anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Comment: are you using micropayments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue already set:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/issues/320

Seems to occur after the v1.8.0 update of the node sdk. According to the description a rollback of the npm package to v1.7.1 seems to work.

EDIT: Just confirmed that by my self. Works.